# Python: printing the products of an element in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to print the product of all elements of an array with len(array) - 1. e.g. array = ['1','10','11']; so 10*11 since 10 and 11 have a length = 2.

I've written the following code but can't seem to find the issue (I keep receiving a 'None').

```
import numpy
def fun(array):
    length = len(array) - 1; " find length of the array "
    for i in range(0,length+1):
        if len(array[i]) == length: 
            """find elements in array with len == length"""
            new_array = []
            new_array.append(array[i])
            "add these elements into a new array"
            for j in range(0,len(new_array)):
                return numpy.prod(int(new_array[j]))
                "find the product of these elements and return them"
            else: break
        else: break
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is that, in python, functions with no explicit return, return None. You have a return in your code, but you're getting None because the code path is not reaching the return statement (see the next issue for more on this). For example the following `bad_abs` function will return None if `a > 0`. You can fix this by making sure that there is a return statement for every code path:

```
def bad_abs(a):
    if a < 0:
        return -a

def good_abs(a):
    if a < 0:
        a = -a
    return a
```

Second, you have a break statement in the else clause of your if statement and the else clause of your inner for loop. Here is an example of how one might use the break statement correctly.

```
def any(array):
    return_value = False
    for item in array:
        if item == True:
            return_value = True
            break # Exit the loop and go to return
    return return_value
```

In your code you do not want a break, in fact breaking after the first non-length item in your array is causeing your code to reach the end of your function and return None. It doesn't seem like you need either else clause, so just take them out.

Last, you're creating an empty list, ie `[]`, at every iteration of your loop, this is deleting the values you found in previous iterations. So you want to make sure you create new_array outside the loop (and please give it a better name).

```
def filter_product(array):
    filtered_array = []
    length = len(array) - 1
    for item in array:
        if len(item) == length:
            filtered_array.append(int(item))
    return numpy.prod(filtered_array)
```

This can be reduced to a 1 line list comprehension, but I find one liners not particularly useful for learning programming.

Comment: There's a return in OP's code: `return numpy.prod(int(new_array[j]))`

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with your code:

1. You're re-defining `new_array = []` each time inside the loop, so the previous appended items are lost.
2. You should append integers instead of simple strings.
3. `numpy.prod` can be applied to the whole array, no need of the second loop.
4. The inner loop is not properly indented.
5. Though this is not wrong, but in python you can iterate over the items of the array/list itself instead of using the indexes.

**Working version:**

```
import numpy
def fun(array):
    length = len(array) - 1; " find length of the array "
    new_array = []
    #iterate over the list itself.
    for item in array:
        if len(item) == length: 
            new_array.append(int(item))
    return numpy.prod(new_array)

print fun(['1','10','11'])
```

**Pure python version:**

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> arr =  ['1','10','11']
>>> reduce(mul, (int(x) for x in arr if len(x) == len(arr)-1))
110
```

Comment: do not use `for i in range(0,length+1):`please, use `for element in array:`

Comment: and list comprehension wopuld be useful here

Comment: @astreal I know, but I am trying to keep the code close to OP's version. I've added a python based solution too.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the code and providing those tips. I've been using a few programming languages and have come back to Python for a bit so I'm used to indexing but I'll make that change.

Answer (score 2):

first of all your code doesn't seems very pythonic, for looping don't use range that way, the `'''` are for docstring whereas `#` is for comments and you use break when you want `continue`.

In your code the code never hit the return if the first element don't have the right length. and it would have return the wrong value.

A simple solution using `numpy` would be (in addition to the one of @hcwhsa using `mul`):

```
import numpy
def fun(array):
    length = len(array) - 1;  # find length of the array
    return numpy.prod([int(x) for x in array if len(x) == length])
```

Comment: Thanks for the pythonic code. I have a tendency not to code this way as I use other programming languages too which use the above structure. But this is still a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = ['1','10','11']
product = 1
for n in numbers:
    if len(n) == 2:
        product *= int(n)
print product
```